# VoiceOver does not correctly scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

When VoiceOver is activated my `UITableView` does not correctly scroll. When the last visible cell is reached and the user swipes with the VoiceOver gesture to the next element the footer view gets selected. The tableView has the style `.grouped`. The correct behaviour would be to go trough all cells and at the end the footer view should be focused. The tableView has a floating section footer view. The footer of the section is a subclass of `UITableHeaderFooterView`. All cells and the footer view are accessible either as an accessibility element or as a container and are sized with auto layout. The view hierarchy looks like this:

[image]
Am I missing something or why is this not working as intended? I was able to get this working in a sample application with a tableView and a section footer view where VoiceOver correctly reads the content.

Comment: Would you mind providing your sample code in a kind of Github in order to answer with the most appropriate elements, please? 